# Handle netstandard1.6 with xUnit

Tags: c#, xunit, .net-core

I am looking to use a test framework for a netstandard1.6 library. I tried to follow and edit [Getting started with xUnit.net (.NET Core / ASP.NET Core)](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html) without success. Follow the xUnit's tutorial with a dotnetcore lib on VS 2015 Update 3 RTM with my project.json file to reproduce the error.

project.json :

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Severity    Code    Description
Error       NU1002  The dependency dotnet-test-xunit 2.2.0-preview2-build1029 does not support framework .NETStandard,Version=v1.0
```

Can I downgrade to a version of .netstandard supported by dotnet-test-xunit 2.2.0-preview2-build1029? Is there any known work around to use xUnit with it?

As I am a bit new project.json and dotnetcore, I might missed something useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked for me. It seems existing xunit versions do not support the netstandard 1.6 library yet. Try changing your project json to look like this as provided for in [xunit site](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html). This also assumes that you created a .net core library project

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
       "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
             "type": "platform",
             "version": "1.0.0"
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can import the **netcoreapp1.0** TFM to convince the tooling that the dependencies are compatible with the target framework:

```
{ 
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta4-build3444",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029" 
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": [ "netcoreapp1.0" ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can find a table of target framework monikers (TFM) in the NuGet documentation linked below, including a table of **deprecated frameworks** which includes **dnxcore50** (replaced by **netcoreapp1.0**):

https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/target-frameworks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the following versions (this is the same, as in asp.net core repos like [Logging](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Test/project.json):

```
"dotnet-test-xunit": "1.0.0-*",
"xunit": "2.1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the available versions for the xunit dependency. I think the 2.2.0 is already final.
2. A xunit project needs to be netcoreapp1.0 and not netstandard.

See their web page for details.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET CLI tool (dotnet) support creating a test project:

```
testproj $ dotnet new -t xunittest
Created new C# project in /home/bartonjs/dotnet/testproj.
testproj $ cat project.json
```

Produces:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.1.1",
    "xunit": "2.1.0",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "1.0.0-rc2-192208-24"
  },
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.4",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Those versions might better lead to success.