# dotNet Standard Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm starting a dotNet core WebAPI  and trying to do the unit tests of the EntityFramework core implementation, I'm using xunit, but when I build the test project it throws the following.

[image: Error]

In the xunit getting started it says that works with the Net Core App  1.0.0 , **so, is there any way to do unit testing with the dotNet Standard v1.6?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dup ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120169/handle-netstandard1-6-with-xunit

Comment: Yeah, it seems so, I didn't saw it. Hmm thanks